# "Error: Phone reports generic communication error or syntax error. (GsmComm.GsmCommunication.CommException)"

Tags: c#, nokia, gsm

i was checking the sample code with gsmComm library, my modem is nokia 5130 Xpressmusic modem and the connection was done successfuly but when i tried to send a SMS .. i got this message

"Error: Phone reports generic communication error or syntax error. (GsmComm.GsmCommunication.CommException)"

what's the problem ?http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/SMS.aspx
is ther any other codes ...

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure that your port is same where you have connected your mobile phone. one method is go to device manager and check COM Port that which PORT is listed there with your phone name. if that port is COM14 let suppose then try to connect at COM15